# Google Cloud Endpoint / How to get json-body request?

Tags: python, api, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to get json body when a POST request is sent to an endpoint.

I defined my methods and classes like this:

```
class UserRequest(messages.Message):
    f1 = messages.IntegerField(1)
    f2 = messages.StringField(2)

class UserResponse(messages.Message):
    content = messages.StringField(1)

USER_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    UserRequest)


@endpoints.api(name='echo', version='v1')

class EchoApi(remote.Service):

@endpoints.method(
    USER_RESOURCE,
    UserResponse,
    path='echo',
    http_method='POST',
    name='echo')
def echo(self, request):
    data = {x.name: getattr(request, x.name) for x in request.all_fields()}
    return UserResponse(content=str(data))
```

When I send a curl post to my endpoint without a body included in :

```
curl -x POST http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo?f1=asdf&f2=qwert
```

I got f1 and f2 with request.f1 and request.f2.

But when I make a curl call with a body :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"f1": "asdf", "f2":"qwert"}' http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo
```

The request object doesn't contains f1 and f2 values, and they are hold in the <*request._Message__unrecognized_fields()*>.

I want to know if it's possible to get directly the json body as a classic request.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a `ResourceContainer`. Just set the request to UserRequest, and that may fix it.